# List Comprehension for 2-D arrays

Tags: python

I have to generate a 2-D array  with a list comprehension. One way to achieve this is as follows

```
size=6
[[0] * size for x in range(0, size)]
```

However the variable `x` is unused here. Is there another way to achieve this? I don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: The output should be

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Comment: @vaultah : This is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Python allows you to use `_` as a variable name. It's Pythonic to use it as a name for unused variables:

```
[[0] * size for _ in range(0, size)]
```